# specific alphadin modification

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I need a BibTex or BibLatex style that creates the following output:

- Max Mustermann --> [Must16]
- Max Mustermann and Susi Beispielfrau --> [MuBe16]
- Max Mustermann and Susi Beispielfrau and Rudi Rüdiger --> [MBR16]
- Max Mustermann and Susi Beispielfrau and Rudi Rüdiger and Albert Peter --> [MBRP16]
- Max Mustermann and Susi Beispielfrau and Rudi Rüdiger and Albert Peter and Fritz Meier --> [MBR+16]
- Max Mustermann and Susi Beispielfrau and Rolf Neumeier and Susi Sorglos and Fritz Meier --> [MBN+16a]
- Max Mustermann and Susi Beispielfrau and Rolf Neumeier and Susi Sorglos and Alfred Müller --> [MBN+16b]
- NN ... --> [NN16a]
- NN ... --> [NN16b]

Am I the only person who needs that formatting? Where do I find such a template or how do I create it? Can somebody create it for me? I can not find any information that helps me as a non-expert.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The title of your posting says, "specific alphadin modification". Are you suggesting that the only thing that should be different about the new bibliography style file is the way the authors' names are abbreviated and arranged to create the citation labels? It would be helpful if you stated how `alphadin` creates the citation labels.

Comment: [Crosspost](http://golatex.de/viewtopic,p,82698.html#82698)

Comment: Just like on goLaTeX, a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html) would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course that information is not enough to properly give a full bibliography style, but you can get the label format easily with `biblatex`.

You will need the options `minalphanames=3, maxalphanames=4, maxbibnames=999` and then

```
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
    \field{label}
    \field[strwidth=4,strside=left,ifnames=1,pcompound=true]{labelname}
    \field[strwidth=2,strside=left,ifnames=2,pcompound=true]{labelname}
    \field[strwidth=1,strside=left,pcompound=true]{labelname}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{year}    
  }
}
```

Of course this requires the Biber back-end.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,backend=biber,minalphanames=3,maxalphanames=4,maxbibnames=999]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{one,
  author = {Max Mustermann},
  year   = {2016},
  title  = {One Author},
}
@book{two,
  author = {Max Mustermann and Susi Beispielfrau},
  year   = {2016},
  title  = {Two Authors},
}
@book{three,
  author = {Max Mustermann and Susi Beispielfrau and Rudi Rüdiger},
  year   = {2016},
  title  = {Three Authors},
}
@book{four,
  author = {Max Mustermann and Susi Beispielfrau and Rudi Rüdiger and Albert Peter},
  year   = {2016},
  title  = {Four Authors},
}
@book{five1,
  author = {Max Mustermann and Susi Beispielfrau and Rudi Rüdiger and Albert Peter and Fritz Meier},
  year   = {2016},
  title  = {Five Authors -- First},
}
@book{five2,
  author = {Max Mustermann and Susi Beispielfrau and Rolf Neumeier and Susi Sorglos and Fritz Meier},
  year   = {2016},
  title  = {Five Authors -- Second},
}
@book{five3,
  author = {Max Mustermann and Susi Beispielfrau and Rolf Neumeier and Susi Sorglos and Alfred Müller},
  year   = {2016},
  title  = {Five Authors -- Third},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
    \field{label}
    \field[strwidth=4,strside=left,ifnames=1,pcompound=true]{labelname}
    \field[strwidth=2,strside=left,ifnames=2,pcompound=true]{labelname}
    \field[strwidth=1,strside=left,pcompound=true]{labelname}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{year}    
  }
}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you! that looks really good. i will study your answer in detail soon.

Comment: stuck again...This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./jobname.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class

! Package keyval Error: pcompound undefined.
      
any idea?

Comment: @r0man3 That is probably because your `biblatex` is too old. Do an update. If that still doesn't work, remove the `pcompound=true`s from the code above, that option was introduced fairly recently.

Comment: I had to remove "pcompound". Now everything works as expected. Thank you, moeve, for the very helpful answer!

Comment: @r0man3 If this answer answered your question, please consider accepting it with the green checkmark, so other people can see that you deemed the solution appropriate.